# Mongod service crashed after performing mongodump

Tags: mongodb, centos7, mongodump

I performed this query

query: mongodump --db=elastic --collection=q_moonx_notifications_2019-08-26 --out=/home/centos/mongo-dump/

on my mongo db to take a dump of one collection which is around

Collection name: q_moonx_notifications_2019-08-26
size : 80GB
storageSize : 23.6GB

Soon after doing this, mongod service crashed.
I went through /var/log/messages to find the problem.
I got to know it happened due to 'out-of-memory' issue.
Can someone help me how it happened and how can I take a dump of a single collection without effecting my running mongo service.

Machine has 32 gb memory and 0 swp.

/var/log/messages content

`Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [<ffffffffbdb61e41>] dump_stack+0x19/0x1b
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [<ffffffffbdb5c86a>] dump_header+0x90/0x229
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [<ffffffffbd700bcb>] ? cred_has_capability+0x6b/0x120
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [<ffffffffbd5ba4e4>] oom_kill_process+0x254/0x3d0
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [<ffffffffbd700c9c>] ? selinux_capable+0x1c/0x40
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [<ffffffffbd5bad26>] out_of_memory+0x4b6/0x4f0
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [<ffffffffbdb5d36e>] __alloc_pages_slowpath+0x5d6/0x724
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [<ffffffffbd5c1105>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x405/0x420
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [<ffffffffbd60df68>] alloc_pages_current+0x98/0x110
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [<ffffffffbd5b6347>] __page_cache_alloc+0x97/0xb0
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [<ffffffffbd5b8fa8>] filemap_fault+0x298/0x490
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [<ffffffffc0400d0e>] __xfs_filemap_fault+0x7e/0x1d0 [xfs]
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [<ffffffffc0400f0c>] xfs_filemap_fault+0x2c/0x30 [xfs]
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [<ffffffffbd5e444a>] __do_fault.isra.59+0x8a/0x100
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [<ffffffffbd5e49fc>] do_read_fault.isra.61+0x4c/0x1b0
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [<ffffffffbd5e93a4>] handle_pte_fault+0x2f4/0xd10
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [<ffffffffbd50cbf8>] ? get_futex_key+0x1c8/0x2c0
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [<ffffffffbd5ebedd>] handle_mm_fault+0x39d/0x9b0
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [<ffffffffbdb6f5e3>] __do_page_fault+0x203/0x500
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [<ffffffffbdb6f915>] do_page_fault+0x35/0x90
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [<ffffffffbdb6b758>] page_fault+0x28/0x30
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: Mem-Info:
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: active_anon:7972560 inactive_anon:30565 isolated_anon:0#012 active_file:2831 inactive_file:4651 isolated_file:0#012 unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:5 unstable:0#012 slab_reclaimable:42065 slab_unreclaimable:12016#012 mapped:18928 shmem:55424 pagetables:19349 bounce:0#012 free:49154 free_pcp:558 free_cma:0
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: Node 0 DMA free:15904kB min:32kB low:40kB high:48kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15988kB managed:15904kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3597 31992 31992
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: Node 0 DMA32 free:121020kB min:7596kB low:9492kB high:11392kB active_anon:3397760kB inactive_anon:11020kB active_file:284kB inactive_file:508kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:3915776kB managed:3684320kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:5892kB shmem:14892kB slab_reclaimable:131668kB slab_unreclaimable:5368kB kernel_stack:1472kB pagetables:7364kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:1184kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:2829 all_unreclaimable? yes
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 28394 28394
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: Node 0 Normal free:66532kB min:59952kB low:74940kB high:89928kB active_anon:28492480kB inactive_anon:111240kB active_file:11040kB inactive_file:11684kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:29622272kB managed:29079004kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:20kB mapped:69820kB shmem:206804kB slab_reclaimable:36592kB slab_unreclaimable:42696kB kernel_stack:6720kB pagetables:70032kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:3320kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:8574 all_unreclaimable? no
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 1*32kB (U) 2*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (M) 3*4096kB (M) = 15904kB
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: Node 0 DMA32: 2724*4kB (UEM) 1319*8kB (UEM) 2734*16kB (UEM) 1065*32kB (UEM) 296*64kB (UEM) 32*128kB (UEM) 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 122312kB
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: Node 0 Normal: 10268*4kB (UEM) 3615*8kB (UEM) 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 69992kB
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: 61902 total pagecache pages
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: 0 pages in swap cache
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: Free swap  = 0kB
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: Total swap = 0kB
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: 8388509 pages RAM
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: 193702 pages reserved
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes swapents oom_score_adj name
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 2415]     0  2415    55590    32605     114        0             0 systemd-journal
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 2456]     0  2456    11953      611      25        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 2704]     0  2704    15511      170      29        0         -1000 auditd
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 4346]    32  4346    18412      189      38        0             0 rpcbind
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 4464]    81  4464    16600      204      34        0          -900 dbus-daemon
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 4532]   998  4532    29446      143      29        0             0 chronyd
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 4588]     0  4588     6652      156      19        0             0 systemd-logind
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 4589]   999  4589   153057     1381      63        0             0 polkitd
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 4592]     0  4592     5416      101      14        0             0 irqbalance
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 4596]     0  4596    50404      162      38        0             0 gssproxy
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 4940]     0  4940    26839      508      51        0             0 dhclient
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 5035]     0  5035   143455     3309      99        0             0 tuned
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 5102]     0  5102    31253      535      58        0             0 nginx
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 5103]   995  5103    31375      641      59        0             0 nginx
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 5104]   995  5104    31375      641      59        0             0 nginx
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 5105]   995  5105    31375      641      59        0             0 nginx
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 5106]   995  5106    31375      641      59        0             0 nginx
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 5107]   995  5107    31375      641      59        0             0 nginx
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 5108]   995  5108    31375      641      59        0             0 nginx
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 5109]   995  5109    31375      641      59        0             0 nginx
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 5110]   995  5110    31375      641      59        0             0 nginx
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 5183]     0  5183    22603      310      42        0             0 master
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 5189]    89  5189    22673      286      43        0             0 qmgr
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 5231]   997  5231  4365796  4120011    8150        0             0 mongod
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 5295]     0  5295   104225    16973     121        0             0 rsyslogd
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 5297]     0  5297    28189      267      58        0         -1000 sshd
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 5337]     0  5337    31580      194      18        0             0 crond
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 5343]     0  5343    27523       50      10        0             0 agetty
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 5347]     0  5347    27523       50      13        0             0 agetty
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 5662]    27  5662   691356    97174     303        0             0 mysqld
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 7361]   996  7361 12739660  2366239    5813        0             0 java
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 7462]   996  7462    17192      173      30        0             0 controller
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 7661]  1000  7661  3588101  1239871    2579        0             0 java
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [14974]     0 14974   371181     6509     107        0             0 metricbeat
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [ 6781]   994  6781   430375    60775     604        0             0 node
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [24008]    89 24008    22629      301      47        0             0 pickup
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [25163]     0 25163    39154      367      77        0             0 sshd
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [25167]  1000 25167    39154      366      74        0             0 sshd
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [25168]  1000 25168    28893      149      15        0             0 bash
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: [28554]  1000 28554   260690    34619     132        0             0 mongodump
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 5231 (mongod) score 503 or sacrifice child
Oct 11 07:07:33 ip-1.23.345.678 kernel: Killed process 5231 (mongod) total-vm:17463184kB, anon-rss:16480044kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Oct 11 07:07:34 ip-1.23.345.678 systemd: mongod.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Oct 11 07:07:34 ip-1.23.345.678 systemd: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Oct 11 07:07:34 ip-1.23.345.678 systemd: mongod.service failed.
Oct 11 07:07:39 ip-1.23.345.678 systemd-logind: New session 1220 of user centos.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [official document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/#back-up-with-mongodump) -

> mongodump reads data from a MongoDB database and creates high fidelity BSON files which the mongorestore tool can use to populate a MongoDB database. mongodump and mongorestore are simple and efficient tools for backing up and restoring small MongoDB deployments, but are not ideal for capturing backups of larger systems.
>
> When connected to a MongoDB instance, mongodump can adversely affect mongod performance. If your data is larger than system memory, the queries will push the working set out of memory, causing page faults.

and for the above said result it is important to have swap memory ready for using these commands.

I would suggest to create swap memory as a first step you can check the required steps for your specific os you are using. This is the best I can recommend for [creating swap space](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-centos-7).

If that doesn't help please increase the memory.

Comment: Can you tell me how much swap memory and memory needed for the each collection like this. I am using centos 7. I have like 7 collections like this

Comment: Thanks for the link and reply. How much swap memory recommended?

Comment: Create around 2 GBs, should be enough.

Comment: Any idea why it took the db down? How that command works? To not repeat the same issue again.

Comment: Thank you so much the explantion @jeet . So, if we have a swap memory of like 2 gig, it’s not going to affect any memory, even if we are dealing with larger collections? Is there any I can use mongodump effiently for my requirement?

Comment: @ManiMK I believe the original question of what caused the crash was correctly answered by Jeet's answer. I suggest you accept the answer, and further questions should belong in a new, separate question.

Comment: @ManiMK also, there is no way to "use mongodump efficiently" since by nature it needs to read the whole collection into memory. By definition it won't be efficient, and the only way to ensure that the dump process run smoothly is to properly plan when the dump will take place and provision a machine that can handle the job without running out of resources.

Comment: @ManiMK See my answer. You ran into a well known (and even documented) behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

You ran into a "problem" called the "OOM-Killer".

A quote from the part of the MongoDB documentation aptly named [Production notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#swap):

> **Swap**
>
> Assign swap space for your systems. Allocating swap space can avoid issues with memory contention and can *prevent* the OOM Killer on Linux systems from *killing mongod*.
>
> For the WiredTiger storage engine, given sufficient memory pressure, WiredTiger may store data in swap space.

(emphasis by me)

What basically happened is that the memory pressure on the system became critical, and the kernel decided to kill a process to free some RAM in order to ensure the system can still run. It does so by determining the "badness" of a task via

```
badness_for_task = total_vm_for_task / (sqrt(cpu_time_in_seconds) *
sqrt(sqrt(cpu_time_in_minutes)))
```

and killing the baddest task. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html
for details.

Gist: MongoDB presumably consumes several orders of magnitude more RAM than any other process on the server, hence it get's killed by the OOM Killer when the Kernel has no option to swap out some data and thereby ensure the basic system tasks still can run.

This behaviour can basically be prevented by allocating swap, which is why it is accordingly documented in the production notes.

Comment: Really given good idea what happened. Thank you @Markus W Mahlberg

Comment: @Markus Really great insight thanks for putting it.